# change widget update interval programatically android

Tags: android, android-widget

I am working on Android widgets in my app. I have a Settings screen from where user can select content of widget and update interval of widget. There is AppWidgetProviderInfo API but don't know how to use it or is there any other way to change widget update interval?
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there any other way to change widget update interval?

Rather than using `android:updatePeriodMillis`, you will need to use `AlarmManager` to arrange to get control and update your app widget. You cannot modify `android:updatePeriodMillis` at runtime.

Comment: @Nuraiz: There may be one, but I do not know of one.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code in your AppWidgetProvider class in the onUpdate void.

```
int updateTime = 1800000; //30 min
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                               System.currentTimeMillis(),
                                updateTime,
                                pendingIntentAlarm);
```

Comment: AppWidgetProvider class doesnt have the `getSystemService()` method, i believe

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the solution provided on this [blog of malubu](http://malubu.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/take-your-time-widgets-and-alarmmanager/)
and check out the source code from [malubu's github](https://github.com/manhluong/Various/tree/master/MaLuBuTestWidget)